# Don't show summary info after selecting a profile tab

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page, mobile-web

When I visit a profile, often I want to find some specific, more in depth information than what's on the landing page. Enter the tabs: questions, answers, reputation, badges, etc. Click "more", receive more of what I want to see. Great.

However, on the mobile site, after clicking a profile tab, I still get my entire screen taken up by the summary information from the landing page.

How obnoxious! I've just told the the site what content I want to see; don't make me scroll to find it. If it's somehow completely infeasible to hide this information when a ran has been clicked - and I don't think that should be the case, given that selecting a tab involves a url change - at least add a chevron or something.

Screenshot below. It's of my profile here on meta, after clicking the answers tab.

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwa6ccVlnBm9RklEUHVTWll4NFk0UmFUXzRyaGs1Y3FpNGN3/view?usp=sharing)</sub>

(That giant banner saying I've earned editing privileges isn't winning points either, as I've had that priv for quite some time.)